# Console Browser says it cannot find a requested image that does not exist on my Website

Tags: images, errors, 404-error

I have a site that I am working on and I noticed that I get this error in my browser console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

It was trying to load a image file called 'bg-10-free-img.jpg'

Now I did look in the console and [I did see this Image file in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWwQn.png) but when I try to go to the link where it should exist, I get an error 404 Page. I even checked in my hosting file directory and nothing with that name came up.

For clarification, this is a site that is running on the latest version of PHP and Wordpress. The site I'm having trouble with is https://starlightdesigning.com

If anyone knows a fix for this issue that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot I see you've put that image in a folder called "Images". When you check the console, it tries to fetch the image in location "/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/bg-10-free-img.jpg". Isn't it simply the case that your URL isn't correct?

Comment: The image that Peter posted is of the content requested by the browser, not the actual file structure on the server.

Comment: What void is saying is correct. The image was long deleted because I did not need it, yet the browser is requesting something that does not exist. I do appreciate the input though

Answer (score 1):

The file is currently being loaded by your theme's css for the footer at:

```
.site-primary-footer-wrap[data-section="section-primary-footer-builder"] {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1, 22, 40, 0.88), rgba(1, 22, 40, 0.88)), url(http://starlightdesigning.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/bg-10-free-img.jpg);
    ....
}
```

This often happens when you delete an image that is being used in the settings of your theme. Go have a look at your themes footer settings and see if there is a background image that you can clear, it might not seem like an image is selected, as the image is deleted. If you can't remove it just select a different image, save the changes, and then remove the newly selected image.

Comment: So I found it under "wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/starlightdesigning.com/about/_index_ssl.html_old" would I be able to delete this whole file since I won't need it?

Comment: Okay so as an update. I didn't find that in the theme's footer. So I am not too sure where else it could be located

Comment: It is likely that your css is being cached, or your theme needs to 'regenerate' its css. Make sure you clear all cache on any caching plugins, or other services like CloudFlare and CDNs. You can also check in your theme settings if there is somewhere to clear cache or regenerate css. If there is a place in your theme's settings to set a background image for the footer then just set it to any image, save, and then clear the image again. This should also 'regenerate' the theme's css.

Comment: As a last option if nothing else works, if you put the css: `.site-primary-footer-wrap[data-section="section-primary-footer-builder"] { background-image: unset!important}` to load somewhere before the theme's css, then the browser should not make a request to the image when loading the theme's css.